# Using jQuery with a href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple(?) question, I have a function which is similar.

```
value = $("input[@name=typeGroup]:checked").val();
if (value == "value1") {
self.doSomething1();
}
else if (value == "value2") {
self.doSomething2();
}
```

Which is used from

```
<div><input type='radio' name='typeGroup' value='value1' data-bind='checked: searchType' />Radio1</div>

<div><input type='radio' name='typeGroup' value='value2' data-bind='checked: searchType' />Radio2</div>
```

The thing is that, I'd like similar option on the function as `$("input[@name=typeGroup]:checked)` but for an `<a href>` which looks like

```
<a href='#' data-bind='click: clickActivateFunction' id='draw_pic'>
```

Is it possible? And how would this look like?

Comment: take care @name is deprecated, remove the @

Comment: `$('#draw_pic')` ??? Note that an anchor is neither checked nor has a value ?

Comment: `data-bind` smells with Knockout.js. If you're using this, you should tag as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the anchor element, you can use:

```
$('#draw_pic')
```

As you have a unique id on that element.

**Update**

If you want to different things, I would bind different events rather than using if statements.

```
$('#draw_pic').click( function () {
    alert('Draw pic clicked');
});

$('#draw_more').click( function () {
    alert('Draw more clicked');
});
```

If it is just a subtle difference, you could use an if statement...

```
$('a').click( function () {
    if (this.id === 'draw_pic') {
        alert('Draw pic clicked');
    }
});
```

Comment: Problem is that I'd like it to check whether it's draw_pic or something else. example:

         `if (value == "value1") {
// do stuff
         }
         else if (value == "value2") {
             // do stuff11
         }`

Comment: You can bind each of those individually, or in a big group. `$('#draw_pic')`... `$('#stoparea')`... or `$('#draw_pic, #stoparea')`

Comment: I'm really sorry for my noobism, does it allow to be
`var value = $('#draw_pic, draw_more')`
And then have a if if else to have a look at which value(id) is being used?

Answer (score 2):

Jquery attribute selector as follows:

```
$("a[href=xxxx]");
```

Updated ans to comment:
use this

```
$("a:contains('My Text')")
```

for using as a function

```
function onclickofa(e) {
    value = $(e.target).text();
    if (value == "value1") {
         self.doSomething1();
    }
    else if (value == "value2") {
        self.doSomething2();
    }
}

<a href="#" onclick="onclickofa()">value1</a>
<a href="#" onclick="onclickofa()">value2</a>
```

Comment: But all my href is set to #, is it possible using value inside of a <a> ? Just like I did on the other function.

Comment: But this locks my value to a certain "text", I want it to look which of those 2 elements, either draw_pic or draw_other. Thats why I have a function which is being called when clicked, and it looks which value it uses in the input, I want it exact same, but instead look inside a <a href> and its id='value1'

Answer (score 1):

The link can be found in the following states:

```
a:link
a:visited
a:hover
a:active
```

Perhaps this is what you need:

```
$("a[href=xxxx]:visited");
```

If you need to bind function with it use [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

Comment: Those locks it to a certain href which is always #. I need it to be set to the ID of the <a> instead.

Comment: This sets the value, I want it to be dynamicly set depending on which of the <a href id="value1"> thats been pressed.

Comment: @SteveFenton wrote what you need, use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a").each(function(){
    var $a = $(this);
    var href = $a.attr("href");
    switch(href)
    {  case '#':
           alert("#!");
       break;
       case "/":
           // special click for home
           $a.click(function(e){
               alert("hello home");
               e.preventDefault();
           });

           // patch href in this case
           $a.attr("href","/index");
       break;
       default:
           alert("href:"+href);
       break;
    }
});
```

Comment: and for support click, replace "each" by "click"

Comment: edited for place special click event and action depending on the href value

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function(e){
   if(this.id === "drawpic"){
      // do something1
     }
   else{
      // do something2
   }
});
```